# Remove dotted outline in Firefox when clicking accepted answer

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, design

With FF (at least in Linux), when you click the accepted answer in any of your questions (or un-accept it) a dotted outline is rendered by the browser this looks quite odd:

[image]

This seems to be reproducible in all of the SE sites, SO for example:

[image]

Unless I'm missing something the solution is quite simple:

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Seems to solve it.

Comment: If only the green checkmark was centered in the orange dotted lines... My ocd sense is tingling.

Comment: Or even simpler: `a { outline: 0 }`

Comment: @meagar's answer makes a good point about accessibility. It is just as easy to `blur()` the link *once it has been clicked*, thus allowing both keyboard navigation and clean visuals.

Answer (score 3):

The browser is *supposed* to visually highlight focused links. Disabling this is a big "screw you" to every person who navigates SE sites primarily by tabbing through elements with the keyboard, and has *huge* implications for the accessibility of the site.